# how to align span with textbox in html list elements?

Tags: html, css, list

I have list of questions and each question will have text box aligned at right corner of the page. I am using html list to display question and each list element has span with css class, It works fine when browser page is 75 % zoom. if i increase/decrease zoom size, the span element is floating across the page.

This is what i have currently

```
.listRight {
    position: absolute; 
    right: 28.5em;
}

<ol style="padding-left:10px">
            <li>some question text. it may be long or short. but the text box should always be displayed properly.
                    <span class="listRight">
                        <input type="text" name="text1" id="text1" dir="rtl"
                        value="7" class
                        aria-required="true" maxlength="4" style="width:4em;float:right;"/>
                    </span>
            </li>
            <li> Question 2 text. Actual text displayed with dummy text. 
                    <span class="listRight">
                        <input type="text" name="text2" id="text2" dir="rtl"
                        value="7" 
                        aria-required="true" maxlength="4" style="width:4em;float:right;"/>
                    </span>
            </li>
<ol>
```

ideal behaviour should be like below.

1. some question text. it may be long or short. but the text box should              text box1
2. question 2 text                                                                   text box2
3. question3 text some arbitrary text                                                text box3

Thansk
chintan

Comment: So you want the `span` to stay within the `li`? Just add `position: relative` to `li`

Comment: if i use <li style="position:relative"> and remove class from span then whole span is moving to left.

Comment: Is this something like what you are trying to do? http://jsfiddle.net/e5q8rhba/